# Setting up IIS Output Caching programatically

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7

I wonder if it's possible to change `Output Caching` values for the `IIS` using `C#` code.

I mean these options:

[image]

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort first.. [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Comment: I know how to ask, I'm not new, but how could I try anything when I haven't found any informations on the web (only caching for web services which doesn't help). I'm looking for some information, because I don't even know what class can help...

Comment: Finally I have found the answer here: [http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching)